# Determine ARM architecture from IDA plugin

Tags: ida, idapython, arm

Writing sandbox plugin for IDA (with IDAPython, but that not the case as it seems) to analyze ARM opcodes, I've came upon following issues:

1) How can I distinct specific ARM architecture (e.g. ARMv5, ARMv7 et cetera) via plugin API? While appropriate arch is clearly stated in IDB header, I've failed to find any suitable API to retrieve that info from plugin.
`idaapi.get_inf_structure() -> procName` 
returns 'ARM' for any ARM ELF/Mach-O binary, as it seems.
Scanning opcodes can be a solution, but I doubt that's a good solution

2) 32/64 flags (i.e. is_32bit/is_64bit) are available to distinguish arm64, for example, fat mach-o's reports +/- for 32-bit (ARMv7) and +/+ for 64-bit (ARM64) IDA. Am I missing something?

3) Is there any best-practice to determine ARM' thumb-instructions mode?
Hadn't go that far yet, stuck with architecture issue...

May be I'm blind?

Comment: Ask on IDA Pro's support forum.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Vitaly, but I've asked this question on stackexchange knowingly, not because I do not know other places to so, or 've never heard of google.
With this particular question I'm looking for suggestions from stackexchange community specifically